# I have data in this link but it still Showing this error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, react-hooks, mongodb-query

[enter image description here][1]```
fetch(`https://tranquil-beach-35648.herokuapp.com/bikes/${inventoryId}`, {
method: 'PUT',
headers: {[enter image description here][2]
'content-type': 'application/json'
},
body: JSON.stringify(quantity)
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => {
console.log('Success', data);
alert('user added Successfully!!');
event.target.reset();
})
// console.log(quantity)
}

```
https://i.ibb.co/WK1bYh6/1.png[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.ibb.co/WK1bYh6/1.png
```

Comment: Show the error message.

Comment: Incomplete question my friend, You'll need to share the error message what kind of error it is plus try formatting your questions nicely so that it becomes better readable.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.